# reading csv file and need to get a dict with month and killed count but getting this error: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

[image]

```
   from csv import DictReader
    with open ('Datasets/year2017.csv') as file_obj:
        file_data = DictReader(file_obj,skipinitialspace =True)
        file_list = list(file_data)
    month_killed = {}
    for row in file_list:
        key = row['Month']
        value  = row['Killed']
        if value != '':
            value = int(float(value))
        else:
            value = 0
    # error is getting from below if statement
        if key in month_killed:
            month_killed[key] += value
        else:
            month_killed = value
    month_killed
```

Answer (score 0):

I would format the code in the question better - it's rather hard to read. But to answer your problem, the image illustrates it rather well - the issue raised on that line `if key in month_killed:` - that error is because `month_killed` is an `int` type, which is not iterable. I guess you had originally had it as a `dict`, but somewhere in the code you assigned it as an `int`.

It seems the below line (again, rather hard to read, so I did a text search) is the culprit for the error that you're having:

```py
month_killed = value
```

So to fix, I'd suggest a key assignment as I believe that's what you'd intended, `month_killed[month] = value` for example should work for that.